# CloudKit data during TestFlight once switching from development to production

Tags: ios, testflight, cloudkit, production

I have recently created a CloudKit app which would send Strings to the record type and update it, and it worked perfectly in the development stage.

However, once I uploaded the build for TestFlight (and it switched to Production) it is no longer updating the data to the production part of cloud kit (it still does changes in the development) Is this a common problem? Is there something in my code that i am missing ?I am wondering if there is a line of code that i need for this to update the production environment instead of the development environment.

Any response would be much appreciated.

[The code which was commented out was initially to add the record type to the container, then the code below is being used to update the data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwIt6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe to make actual changes to the production environment you need to make a new target for your app that is pointed at production instead of development. Also, you can only make changes in production using a physical device once you get it setup.

[This helped me get mine setup and working in production!](https://blog.frozenfirestudios.com/setting-up-a-cloudkit-project-ca9ac1883511#.sxaippahe)

Cheers!